# The Windows 10 Emoji Keyboard does not react to user entry

Tags: windows-10, emoji-keyboard

I have two systems, one has the emoji keyboard working just fine. For the second system, the Emoji Keyboard pops up when I press windows+., but then it seems to be completely detatched. It does not react to keyboard input, not even to "escape", which normally closes the emoji keyboasrd. Also, when I press an emoji, it is not transmitted to the application behind it.

The solutions I found on google (e.g. different input language, installing voice recognition packs, restart, ...) did not work.

Of the programs I have installed that might capture keyboard input I installed the same, or less, on the computer where it doesn't work. The only application that would actually capture user input would be Mouse Without Borders, but said emoji input was already broken before I first installed that.

My primary input language is german.

Any idea what I can try to fix this issue without reinstalling the entire system?

Comment: I was unable reproduce the behavior you describe on a clean install of 21H1.  I was able to launch the Emoji window, but i was able to interact with it, the text appeared in the search box on the taskbar.  Of course that is due to the fact that is the textbox that was active.  Any textbox on any application would "search" the list of Emojis

Comment: I am not able to reproduce my behavior on another machine either, doesn't mean it's not an issue for me.